# iOS memory leak with method [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:xxx]

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiimage

I use Instruments Leaks tool found 409 new leak in method [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:xxxxx]

Anyone encounter this problem? Who can tell me?

[image: error info]

Comment: Don't post images of code. And no, you didn't find 409 leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not memory leak,but is xcode profile's bugs. So you can ignore this warnings